# How to access Dataannotation's "GroupName" in mvc view?

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I want to access `DataAnnotation`'s `GroupName` in MVC view.
For example, let's say one of my model properties is like

```
[Display(Order = 1, GroupName= "Passport Detail", Name = "Passport #")]
[Required()]
[StringLength(20)]
public string PassportNo { get; set; }
```

Now, How can I access the `GroupName` in the view?
I want to achieve something like [this](http://csharpbits.notaclue.net/2010/02/grouping-field-on-details-edit-and.html) in **MVC**.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a workaround solution.
We can achive this by using DataAnnotationsModelMetadataProvider.
For Ex.

```
public class MetadataProvider : DataAnnotationsModelMetadataProvider
{
    protected override ModelMetadata CreateMetadata(IEnumerable<Attribute> attributes,
                                                    Type containerType, Func<object> modelAccessor,
                                                    Type modelType, string propertyName)
    {
        var metadata = base.CreateMetadata(attributes, containerType, modelAccessor, modelType, propertyName);

        var disp = attributes.OfType<DisplayAttribute>().FirstOrDefault();
        if (disp != null)
        {
            if (disp.GroupName != null)
                metadata.AdditionalValues.Add("GroupName", disp.GroupName);
        }

        return metadata;
    }
}
```

In the mvc view we can use [AdditionalValues](http://geekswithblogs.net/michelotti/archive/2011/01/30/mvc-3-additionalmetadata-attribute-with-viewbag-to-render-dynamic-ui.aspx) as usual.

Answer (score 2):

I was looking into this as well and it seems like you have to do a lot of code for an attribute that should simply just be there...right??

Rather than having to extend the current logic, I went with the [AdditionalValuesAttribute](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.additionalmetadataattribute%28v=vs.98%29.aspx) to define my own "GroupName". Of course you can get all "fancy pants" with extending this, but it basically works like so:

```
    if (ViewData.ModelMetadata.AdditionalValues.ContainsKey("GroupName")) {
        var groupName = ViewData.ModelMetadata.AdditionalValues["GroupName"].ToString();
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, I dont see that MVC uses that.  DataAnnotations is not really part of MVC so all props may not be used.  If you wanted to use it I would say you need to create an HTML helper that could create those groups.

Ok, I think I see what you might want... you want it to auto template it for you.  Just use the EditorTemplates.  http://www.codecapers.com/post/Display-and-Editor-Templates-in-ASPNET-MVC-2.aspx

Comment: Thanks for replying. It helped to me find the solution.

Answer (score 0):

**How About This!!! must work :**

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;
using System.Linq;
using System.Linq.Expressions;
using System.Reflection;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Mvc;

namespace System.Web.Mvc
{
    public static class DisplayGroup
    {
        public static MvcHtmlString DisplayGroupName(this HtmlHelper helper, string groupName)
        {
            return MvcHtmlString.Create(groupName);
        }

        public static MvcHtmlString DisplayGroupNameFor<TModel, TValue>(this HtmlHelper<TModel> html, Expression<Func<TModel, TValue>> expression)
        {
            var type = typeof(TModel);
            PropertyInfo propertyInfo = null;

            var member = (MemberExpression)expression.Body;
            var property = (PropertyInfo)member.Member;
            var name = property.Name;

            var metadataTypeInfo = type.GetCustomAttribute<MetadataTypeAttribute>();

            if (metadataTypeInfo != null)
            {
                var metadataType = metadataTypeInfo.MetadataClassType;
                propertyInfo = metadataType.GetProperties().Where(x => x.Name == name).FirstOrDefault();
                if (propertyInfo == null)
                {
                    propertyInfo = type.GetProperties().Where(x => x.Name == name).FirstOrDefault();
                }
            }
            else
            {
                propertyInfo = type.GetProperties().Where(x => x.Name == name).FirstOrDefault();
            }

            string output = "";

            var dattr = propertyInfo.GetCustomAttribute<DisplayAttribute>();
            if (dattr != null)
            {
                if (dattr.GroupName == null)
                {
                    output = propertyInfo.Name;
                }
                else
                {
                    output = dattr.GroupName;
                }
            }
            else
            {
                output = propertyInfo.Name;
            }

            return MvcHtmlString.Create(output);
        }

    }
}




public class MyModel
    {
        [Display(Name = "Number",GroupName="Invoice")]
        string InvNo { get; set; }
    }
```

and then simply write :

```
@Html.DisplayGroupNameFor(x => x.InvNo)
```

**Note :**
NameSpace should be : `System.Web.Mvc`

**Update :** 
The cool thing is that , if you have a `MetaDataType` class defined for your dataAnnotation , then also this will work as expected.